# sqlplus output redirected to csv file using batch script contains quotes

Tags: batch-file, csv, sqlplus, quotes, invisible

We have a bat file like this which is executed on oracle db

```
sqlplus -s user@SID/"PWD" @D:\sql_query.sql > D:\test.csv
```

sql_query.sql file contains sql like:

```
SET Heading Off Linesize 4000
set pagesize 0
SELECT 4 || ';' || 1 || ';' || table_name.column_name || ';' ||  table_name.column_name
FROM Table;
EXIT
```

but in some lines of csv output file we are getting invisible quotes (") which are visible only in text and not in excel, (there is no specific trend for quotes it is random).
csv output

```
4;1;4;1024
"1;2;4;1024"
4;1;4;1026
4;1;5;1025
4;1;8;1023
```

in this output entire 2nd line is coming in quotes, which is causing data import to fail in postgres.

we have 10-20 hundred thousands rows in csv and cannot remove this quotes manually, and we want all this steps to be automated.

any reply will be highly appreciated.

Comment: See also: [Unexpected double quote during the CSV file export in SQL Server Reporting Services](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/330048/unexpected-double-quote-during-the-csv-file-export-in-sql-server-reporting-services)